# Is this a topological manifold?

Tags: manifolds

Consider the map $w \rightarrow (w^3, w^2)$ from $\mathbb{C}$ to $ \mathbb{C}^2$. Is the image of this map a topological manifold?

I think the map is bijective and continuous, but is not a homeomorphism at $0$. So I don't know whether the image is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ around $(0,0)$.

Comment: Why do you think the map is not a homeomorphism at $0$?

Comment: The inverse is $y_1 / y_2$ and it's undefined at (0,0)

Comment: But it *can* be defined at $(0,0)$ so that it is continuous on the image of your map, can't it?

Comment: The inverse is continuous, but not differentiable, right?

Answer (score 3):

Your map $f:\mathbb C\to \mathbb C^2: w\mapsto (x,y)=(w^3,w^2)$ is a homeomorphism onto its image (endowed with the subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb C^2$).
 Thus the image  is a topological manifold since $\mathbb C$ is one.

Since $f$ is clearly continuous and bijective, the only non-trivial point in the argument above
is that $f$ is a closed map.
And the reason for that  is that $f$ is [proper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_map) ( proper maps are closed !): indeed, when  $w$ tends to infinity  $f(w)$ tends to infinity too.

[As an aside, the image of $f$ is the algebraic subset of $\mathbb C^2$ with equation $x^2-y^3=0$ ]

Comment: It's not clear why you introduce $(x,y)$, since you never use that notation.

Comment: But I **do** use that notation,  my dear @Thomas: where did you stop reading my answer ?